# Apache httpd compile (make) error. How to fix it?

Tags: apache, compilation

I get an error when compiling (configure) Apache httpd. Please tell me how to solve it.

- Error message

```
$ git clone -b 2.2.3 --single-branch https://github.com/apache/httpd.git
$ cd httpd
$ autoconf
$ ./configure
configure: error: cannot find required auxiliary files: config.guess config.sub
```

- My environment

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ autoconf -V
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.71
```

---

Update 1

The "configure" problem has probably been solved. (I stopped using github). However, an error occurs during make.

- "make" error message

```
$ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.3.tar.gz
$ gzip -d httpd-2.2.3.tar.gz
$ tar xvf httpd-2.2.3.tar
$ cd httpd-2.2.3
$ ./configure --prefix /home/ubuntu/local
$ make

/usr/bin/ld: .libs/htpasswd.o: undefined reference to symbol 'crypt@@XCRYPT_2.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:39: htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/httpd-2.2.3/support'
make[1]: *** [/home/ubuntu/httpd-2.2.3/build/rules.mk:72: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/httpd-2.2.3/support'
make: *** [/home/ubuntu/httpd-2.2.3/build/rules.mk:72: all-recursive] Error 1
```

- Installed modules

```
sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.2.3.tar.gz
tar -xf httpd-2.2.3.tar.gz
sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/httpd --with-included-apr --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-1.0.1i --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps --enable-mods-static=ssl
sudo make
sudo make install
```